# Is set a param for CharField like upload_to param for FileField possible?

Tags: python, django

I have a WorkOrderUploadFile model like bellow:

```
class WorkOrderUploadFile(models.Model):
    wo_num = models.CharField(max_length="16")
    filepath = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="images/qiyun_admin_servicemanage_workorder/")
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_files_directory)
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

You see, for the FileField there is a `upload_to` param, so I can use the `generate_files_directory` method to generate the file field value.

Is is possible to set a method for CharField param? (because the `wo_num` CharField is need use a method to generate the number.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `default` argument to pass the function but that function not taking any arugment does upload_to.

models.py

```
def generate_random():
    return random_number

class WorkOrderUploadFile(models.Model):
    wo_num = models.CharField(max_length="16", default=generate_random)
```